# Select MAX-date from Data table dt on condition

Tags: c#

```
*VC_DEVID*  *DT_LODDATE*               *C_INPUTMODE*    *DT_ALTERDATE*
DEVC109         29/Apr/2013 12:50:29        R           30/Apr/2013 12:50:29
DEVC110         29/Apr/2013 12:50:29        M           29/Apr/2013 12:50:29
DEVC111         29/Apr/2013 12:50:29        M           28/Apr/2013 12:50:29
DEVC112         29/Apr/2013 12:50:29        M           27/Apr/2013 12:50:29
DEVC109         29/Apr/2013 12:50:29        R           26/Apr/2013 12:50:29
```

this is what in my Datatable returs..
I need to select the maximum alterdate  where `c_INPUTMODE='C'` on a string variable

pls help

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LINQ to DataSet/DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) for this purpose like:

```
DateTime maxDate = dt.AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(r => r.Field<string>("C_INPUTMODE") == "C")
                      .Max(r => r.Field<DateTime>("DT_ALTERDATE"));
```

Or

```
DateTime maxDate = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("C_INPUTMODE") == "C")
            .Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>("DT_ALTERDATE"))
            .Max();
```

If your Column `C_INPUTMODE` is of `char` type then your where clause should be:

```
.Where(r=> r.Field<char>("C_INPUTMODE") == 'C')
```

Comment: it shows a error on dt.AsEnumerable() and char < ("C_INPUTMODE") under that < symbol

Comment: @user2305958, Check the latest answer, there was a typo, it should be `<char>`

Comment: error still on As Enumerable() _> shows System.Data.DataTable doesnot contain a definition for asEnumerable

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` on top of the code, also make sure you have reference to `DataSetExtension`  in your project references.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dt.* 
FROM 
dt, 
( SELECT max(dt_alterdate) 
  FROM dt 
  where c_inputmode='C') 
AS maxdate 

WHERE maxdate.vc_devid=dt.vc_devid
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it

Comment: thanx all got it 

 DataRow[] dRows = dt.Select("DT_ALTERDATE=MAX(DT_ALTERDATE) and C_INPUTMODE='R'");
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dRows)
                    {
                        objReset.prpDtreset = dr[3].ToString() ;
                    }